# php with embedded javascript outputs newlines on HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, themes

I have a php page with JavaScript to be used on a wordpress page,but when the page is generated all `<div>` `<p>` etc. appends new lines. Example :

Test.php ->

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('hello<div>world</div>');
</script>
```

When I view-source there is new lines on each html-tags : 'div' - which breaks the JavaScript syntax

[view-source-picture](http://hapti.co/php-newlines.PNG)

I really don't get it

Thanks

Comment: Is `Alert` work for you ? I think it is case sensitive.

Comment: sorry a few typos - did it from my ipad - let me correct it

Comment: sorry for all the "changes" I am new to submitting questions here :)

Comment: Why would you alert html stuff at all? If you want to style your alert, use a [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) for instance.

Comment: that's not the issue, the reason for the alerts are just for debug, because the javascript generated by the WP plugin is not working

Comment: User `console.log` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature of WordPress called `wpautop`. It will insert `<br>` and `<p>` tags automatically, depending on the number of newlines you use in your editor. You can disable this globally by creating a new plugin with this single line of code. (Or, alternatively, put this in your themes `function.php`)

```
<?php remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');
```

However, this might break other pages, so minifying your Javascript into a single line is probably the better alternative.

Comment: the remove filter is present in the themes function.php - I also tried to add it just before the <script in the test.php file

Comment: the javascript is generated by a plugin, so can't change all the code - I tried to post a picture of the view-source, but I can't with my new account here

Comment: wpautop was the right direction, I had to change code in the theme I am using - bypassing wpautop(xxx) when it contains a  "<script type....> block

Comment: @user3052628 Bad theme, you don't manually call `wpautop`, it is supposed to be used as filter only. Hope you didn't pay money for that.